# How do I get Snort to log the packets that match a given rule?

Tags: windows, packet, rules, packet-capture, snort

I'd like my Snort IDS to log all traffic from any IP address on any port that comes to my machine through any well-known port. I've set up my snort.conf file appropriately and saved the following rule in the rules folder:

`log tcp any any -> 192.168.100.65 53639`.

In a command prompt window, I've tried various commands:
`snort -i4 -c C:\Snort\etc\snort.conf -A console`
`snort -i4 -c C:\Snort\etc\snort.conf -A console > C:\Snort\log\test.txt`

both of which created empty files in the log folder, which were deleted once I hit Ctrl+C to stop the snort process, most likely because no information was logged to them.

If you can provide any pointers, I'd really appreciate it.